# Why my pickle database that is in my game doesnt work

Tags: python, database

I have mini-program, in which You can registrant and start play game. My **pickle** database doesnt work. And I cant understand what I have done wrong. To create an account in my program you must press on the registration button, then you must press the sign-in button and enter the username, and the password.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import pyttsx3
import pickle
import time
import smtplib
import string

# Personal office of user
class PersonalOffice:
    def __init__(self, username, mail, best_score):
        self.username = username
        self.mail = mail
        self.best_score = best_score
    def render(self, master):
        personal_office_label = tk.Label(
            master=master,
            text="Your name is: " + str(self.username),
            pady=90,
            font=('Arial', 16)
        )
        personal_office_label.pack()

        username_label = tk.Label(
            master=master,
            text="Your name is: " + str(self.username),
            pady=105,
            font=('Arial', 14)
        )
        username_label.pack()

        mail_label = tk.Label(
            master=master,
            text="Your mail is: " + str(self.mail),
            pady=110,
            font=('Arial', 14)
        )
        mail_label.pack()

        best_score_label = tk.Label(
            master=master,
            text="Your best score is: " + str(self.best_score),
            pady=115,
            font=('Arial', 14)
        )
        best_score_label.pack()

""" bd variables """
# name of user
username_reg = ""
# mail of user
mail_reg = ""
# password of user
password_reg = ""

# sign in username and password
username_s, password_s = "", ""

engine = pyttsx3.init()

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

def Start():
    pass

def Quit(): 
    sys.exit()

def CreateAccount():
    global username_reg, mail_reg, password_reg
    db = {
        "username": username_reg.get(),
        "mail": mail_reg.get(),
        "password": password_reg.get(),
        "best_score": 0
    }

    file = open("db/users.pkl", "wb")
    pickle.dump(db, file)
    file.close()

    now_signin = tk.Toplevel()
    now_signin.geometry("540x100")
    now_signin.overrideredirect(True)
    now_signin.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    text = tk.Label(now_signin, text="Now, as you have account you can sign in, or sign out", font=('Arial', 14))
    text.pack()

    def quit_toplevel():
        now_signin.destroy()

    quit_btn_toplevel = tk.Button(now_signin, text="Quit", background="#fff",
                                  padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=quit_toplevel)
    quit_btn_toplevel.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=30, width=130)

def SignAccount():
    global username_s, password_s

    file = open("db/users.pkl", "rb")
    print(pickle.load(file))
    for i in pickle.load(file):
        if i["username"] == username_s.get() \
            and i["password"] == password_s.get():
            reg_btn.destroy()
            signin_btn.destroy()

            HOST = "mySMTP.server.com"
            SUBJECT = "SnakeBoom"
            TO = i["mail"]
            FROM = "arthurtopal342@gmail.com"
            text = "Success! You have sign in your account in SnakeBoom. Now you can remember your best result. \n\n To contact with write arthurtopal342@gmail.com. \n Funny game!"

            BODY = "\r\n".join((
                "From: %s" % FROM,
                "To: %s" % TO,
                "Subject: %s" % SUBJECT,
                "",
                text
            ))

            server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST)
            server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
            server.quit()

            # create personal office of current user


    file.close()

def Reg():
    global username_reg, mail_reg, password_reg

    reg = tk.Tk()
    reg.geometry("500x400")
    reg.title("Create new account")
    reg.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    reg_name = tk.Label(reg, text="Registration", pady=60, font=('Arial', 18))
    reg_name.pack()

    ure = tk.Label(reg, text="Enter username", font=('Arial', 12))
    ure.pack()
    username_reg = tk.StringVar()
    username_regE = tk.Entry(reg, textvariable=username_reg, width=40)
    username_regE.pack()

    mre = tk.Label(reg, text="Enter mail", font=('Arial', 12))
    mre.pack()
    mail_reg = tk.StringVar()
    mail_regE = tk.Entry(reg, textvariable=mail_reg, width=40)
    mail_regE.pack()

    pre = tk.Label(reg, text="Enter password", font=('Arial', 12))
    pre.pack()
    password_reg = tk.StringVar()
    password_regE = tk.Entry(reg, textvariable=password_reg, width=40)
    password_regE.pack()

    ready_reg = tk.Button(reg, text="Registration ready", background="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=CreateAccount)
    ready_reg.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=190)

    reg.mainloop()

def SignIn():
    global username_s, password_s
    reg = tk.Tk()
    reg.geometry("500x400")
    reg.title("Sign in existed account")
    reg.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    signin_name = tk.Label(reg, text="Sign in", pady=60, font=('Arial', 18))
    signin_name.pack()

    use = tk.Label(reg, text="Enter username", font=('Arial', 12))
    use.pack()
    username_s = tk.StringVar()
    username_sE = tk.Entry(reg, textvariable=username_s, width=40)
    username_sE.pack()

    pse = tk.Label(reg, text="Enter password", font=('Arial', 12))
    pse.pack()
    password_s = tk.StringVar()
    password_sE = tk.Entry(reg, textvariable=password_s, width=40)
    password_sE.pack()

    ready_reg = tk.Button(reg, text="sign in", background="#fff",
                          padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=SignAccount)
    ready_reg.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=190)

    reg.mainloop()

def SignOut():
    pass

screen = tk.Tk()
screen.title("SnakeBoom - Arthur Topal, arthurtopal342@gmail.com")
screen.geometry("460x600")
screen.resizable(width=False, height=False)

name = tk.Label(screen, text="SnakeBoomツ", font=("Arial", 24), pady=30)
name.pack()

start_btn = tk.Button(screen, text="Start", background="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=Start)
start_btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=30, width=130)

quit_btn = tk.Button(screen, text="Quit", background="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=Quit)
quit_btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=30, width=130)

reg_btn = tk.Button(screen, text="Registration", background="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=Reg)
reg_btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=230)

signin_btn = tk.Button(screen, text="Sign In", background="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=SignIn)
signin_btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.86, anchor="c", height=30, width=230)

signout_btn = tk.Button(screen, text="Sign Out", background="#fff", padx="20", pady="8", font=('Arial', 16), command=SignOut)
signout_btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.92, anchor="c", height=30, width=230)

# speak("Welcome to the Snake Boom, to start game please sign in or registrant, and press button Start. To quit press button quit")

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are there any errors? Can users login or does that fail?

Comment: Yes, my pickle database stores user's data incorrectly and when i check if printed text and password is the same as saved data in the *.pkl file, there is TypeError that i am trying to get non integer index in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to help...  I'm no `tk` expert, but your data is a little wonky.

- print out the data that you intend to write to the file.  I'm getting all empty strings, this is a tk thing...not sure why
- You are writing a dictionary with one user in it.  I think you want either a list of dictionaries or a dictionary of dictionaries keyed by user name.  If you want to do a list, because you are checking them with iteration, you can try:

--

```
db = []
entry = {
    "username": username_reg.get(),
    "mail": mail_reg.get(),
    "password": password_reg.get(),
    "best_score": 0
}
db.append(entry)
print(f'about to write: {db}')     # for error checking
file = open("db/users.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(db, file)
file.close()
```

- When you are reading it back in, you only get to read it **once**.  You are attempting to read it twice without closing the file.  Try this:

--

```
file = open("db/users.pkl", "rb")
data = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
print(f'Received from file: {data}')
for i in data:   # do not re-read the data here, it will be empty!
    ....
```

Note:  You need to think about the data container for your users.  I would suggest a dictionary of dictionaries.  Outer key would be username, then each sub-dictionary would contain that user data

Comment: Thank you very much